# Python 3.5: Exporting Chinese Characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have been trying several times to export Chinese from list variables to csv or txt file and found problems with that.

Specifically, I have already set the encoding as utf-8 or utf-16 when reading the data and writing them to the file. However, I noticed that I cannot do that when my Window 7’s base language is English, even that I change the language setting to Chinese. When I run the Python programs under the Window 7 with Chinese as base language, I can successfully export and show Chinese perfectly.

I am wondering why that happens and any solution helping me show Chinese characters in the exported file when running the Python programs under English-based Window?

Comment: Can Chinese shows normally in your English Win7? I mean you may check their encoding first. BTW, are you Chinesse?

Comment: Please include code so that other people can reproduce your issue. Please check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I just found that you need to do 2 things to achieve this:

1. Change the Window's display language to Chinese.
2. Use encoding UTF-16 in the writing process.

Comment: You do not need to change the display language to Chinese, unless you are trying to view the file in a Windows console, which defaults to a localized codepage (CP437 on US Windows, for example).  GUI programs such as Notepad, Word, etc., can display UTF-8 text files as long as the font being used supports the characters.

Answer (score -1):

Here's US Windows 10, running a Python IDE called PythonWin.  There are no problems with Chinese.

[image]

Here's the same program running in a Windows console.  Note the US codepage default for the console is `cp437`.  `cp65001` is UTF-8.  Switching to an encoding that supports Chinese text is the key.  The text below was cut-and-pasted directly from the console.  While the characters display correctly pasted to Stack Overflow, the console font didn't support Chinese and actually displayed [image].

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 437

C:\>x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\x.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(f.read())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to <undefined>

C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>type test.txt
我是美国人。
C:\>x
我是美国人。
```

Notepad displays the output file correctly as well:

[image]

Either use an IDE that supports UTF-8, or write your output to a file and read it with a tool like Notepad.

Ways to get the Windows console to actually output Chinese are the `win-unicode-console` package, and changing the Language and Region settings, Administrative tab, system locale to Chinese.  For the latter, Windows will remain English, but the Windows console will use a Chinese code page instead of an English one.

Comment: ok, but this does not work for my machine with WinPython. For my case, I have to change the Window's display language. Thanks for your comments, anyway.